# How can I format a MySQL TIMEDIFF without seconds?

Tags: mysql, time

I'm running this `SELECT` statement:

```
TIMEDIFF(NOW(), posts.date_modified) as time_ago
```

And getting results in the format `02:58:32`. The last set of digits, `:32`, are the number of seconds.

How can I omit the seconds?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), posts.date_modified), '%H:%i') AS time_ago
```

Consult the [manual for more on `TIME_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format) and a table of allowed specifiers.